# Return data from an array

Tags: php

i'm working with the compete api to retrieve the unique visitors to a site..here's the code..

```
$activityurl = file_get_contents("http://apps.compete.com/sites/facebook.com/trended/uv/?apikey=myapikey");

$jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl);

foreach($jsondecoded as $values)
{

    print_r($values)."<br />";
}
```

This is the output i get..

```
OKstdClass Object ( [trends] => stdClass Object ( [uv] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201210 [value] => 160962051 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201211 [value] => 163640791 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201212 [value] => 165602717 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201301 [value] => 166238881 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201302 [value] => 165056717 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201303 [value] => 164808579 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201304 [value] => 164131054 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201305 [value] => 163323608 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201306 [value] => 163078120 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201307 [value] => 163864002 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201308 [value] => 163413311 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201309 [value] => 164616160 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201310 [value] => 167403281 ) ) )
```

i would like to retrieve the 'value' from the above

Comment: `$jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl, true);`

Comment: $jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract them in a loop

```
$activityurl = file_get_contents("http://apps.compete.com/sites/facebook.com/trended/uv/?apikey=myapikey");

$jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl);
$values = array();

if ($jsondecoded->status === 'ACCESS_DENIED') throw new Exception($jsondecoded->status_message);

foreach($jsondecoded->data->trends->uv as $object)
{
    $values[] = $object->value;
}
```

`var_dump($values)` gives

```
array(13) {
  [0] =>
  int(160962051)
  [1] =>
  int(163640791)
  [2] =>
  int(165602717)
  [3] =>
  int(166238881)
  [4] =>
  int(165056717)
  [5] =>
  int(164808579)
  [6] =>
  int(164131054)
  [7] =>
  int(163323608)
  [8] =>
  int(163078120)
  [9] =>
  int(163864002)
  [10] =>
  int(163413311)
  [11] =>
  int(164616160)
  [12] =>
  int(167403281)
}
```

Comment: returns a notice 'Undefined property: stdClass::$uv'

Comment: Yes, it's `->trends->uv` not `->uv->trends` (sorry). Please try again!

Comment: still gets a notice on 'Trying to get property of non-object' for the foreach line

Comment: The above code has been tested and **works guaranteed**. You're probably over your daily query limit. I've added an `if` statement to check that. If so, you need to try later (or use another key).

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a such way:

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl, true);
```

Second param means:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

I hope you know how to work with arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode($activityurl,true);  //u will get array type
```

then u can do

```
 $trends=$jsondecoded['trends'];

 $uv=$trends['uv'];

foreach $uv as $target
{
 echo $target['data'].' '. $target['value'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: returns a warning 'Undefined index: trends'

Comment: can you give detail about $activityurl

Comment: $activityurl captures the unique visitors from the compete api..the compete api is used to provide web analytics and takes the following structure.. https://apps.compete.com/sites/DOMAIN/trended/METRIC/?apikey=APIKEY .. where 'METRIC' is the code of the metric you are requesting (e.g., Unique Visitors, Visits, Rank)